# Nginx pnp4nagios with php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, php

I have been going at this for a day now. And I think it's time to ask for help now.

I'm moving our nagios to nginx. I have nagios running as well as a django application I recently developed. Pnp4nagios is giving me some troubles though. I have the following configuration in Nginx.

```
location ~ ^(/pnp4nagios/.*\.php)(.*)$ {
    root /usr/share/pnp4nagios/html;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    rewrite ^/pnp4nagios/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/share/pnp4nagios/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

This results in this:
[image: Folder Wrong]

As you can see, pnp4nagios thinks that its index.php lives in 172.16.10.28/index.php But this isn't true. It is a sub-page (or whatever i should call it?). I want it to point to 172.16.10.28/pnp4nagios/index.php but I have no clue how I can do this in my nginx config. I would prefer not to change anything in pnp4nagios. But if it's only one or a few lines it's a compromise I'm willing to make. I already have an index.php in my "root" url. That's why I want a subfolder.

The examples that have lead me to this aproach are:
[Example1](http://www.barrymorrison.com/2011/05/nginx-nagios-pnp4nagios-working-conf-file/)
[Example2](https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Setting+up+PNP+and+Icinga+with+Nginx)

So to recap what I want (or what I think that I need) is to go from this: `img src="/index.php...` to `img src="/pnp4nagios/index.php...`

PS. I didn't have enough points to create a pnp4nagios tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
location /pnp4nagios {
    alias /usr/share/pnp4nagios/html;
}   

location ~ ^(/pnp4nagios.*\.php)(.*)$ {
    root /usr/share/pnp4nagios/html;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a rewrite in your configuration that strips php4nagios path component. Therefore it's not surprising to see the reference to `/index.php`. You should verify the resulting CGI variables using an `info.php` page in the appropriate directory. The offending line is:

`rewrite /pathinfo/(.*)/ $1 break;`